# How to show Image Alt Value with View Slideshow Module?

Tags: views, theming, nodes

I am working on the Image Slide show using  [View Slide show](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)  module in drupal 8.Its working fine for Image Slide show but I want to know How can I show the Image Alt value below the Image and its change with the slideshow.[image]

[image]